# How to instantiate Scala 3 enum from generic type

Tags: scala, generics, enums, scala-3

Say I have a method in Scala 3 with the following signature:

```
def foo[E <: scala.reflect.Enum](str: String): E
```

How can I instantiate E according to str?

If for example, E is:

```
enum MyEnum:
  case a1, a2
```

Then I want the function to return MyEnum.a1 for str = "a1", MyEnum.a2 for str = "a2", and to throw an exception for other values of str.

Comment: Not sure whether it can work in general: What is it supposed to do for `enum Foo { case Bar(n: Int); case Baz(s: String) }`? Bootstrap a parser for parenthesized expressions? Feels as if stringy data somehow slipped yhrough deserialization stage: usually, this kind of murky stringy data is eliminated by circe & co.

Comment: @AndreyTyukin I indeed need to do this for json reads and writes. but I use play-json which only has a formatter for the old Scala enumerations. So I'm looking for a way to implement the formatter myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found this library which does it without runtime reflection:
https://github.com/bishabosha/enum-extensions

Answer (score 0):

```
def foo[E <: scala.reflect.Enum](str: String)(using ct: ClassTag[E]): E = {
  val values = ct.runtimeClass.getMethod("values").invoke(null).asInstanceOf[Array[E]]
  values.find(_.toString == str).getOrElse(throw Exception("not found"))
}
```

then it can be invoked: `foo[MyEnum]("a1")`

drawback is it used reflection, so not good for performance sensitive code.